# Enable expand/collapse buttons for Outlines/Groups on a protected worksheet in SpreadsheetGear

Tags: spreadsheetgear

Is there a way to still toggle the expand/collapse buttons for Outlines/Groups in SpreadsheetGear even when the sheet has IWorksheet.[ProtectContents](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~ProtectContents.html) set to true?
Thanks.

Comment: There are not enough specifics and context to easily or concisely answer this question.  Please clarify a couple things.  Firstly, by "outlined toggle button" are you referring to a Check Box Form Control, or something else?  Secondly, regarding worksheet protection (ProtectContents==true), is not clear what the actual problem is.  I have some guesses as to what this might be, but the question needs to be clear on this.  Please modify your question to include these details.

Comment: Sorry, 
For the "outlined toggle button" , it's a control that appears on the left or the top of the workbookview when you group some rows or columns, wich allow to expand or collapse this. 
For the ProtectContents at true, if i use it ,i can't click on this control.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I am going to modify your original post to better reflect this information (feel free to further modify if I'm still missing something), then provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

SpreadsheetGear 2023 / V9 is now available and supports expanding / collapsing groups on a protected worksheet via an enhancement in supporting more fine-grained worksheet protection options--in particular allowing formatting on rows and / or columns:

```
// Create a new workbook and some local variables to the worksheet and cells.
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

// Add outlines to both rows and columns.
cells["2:10"].EntireRow.Group();
cells["B:D"].EntireColumn.Group();

// Enable ProtectContents to enable worksheet protection (without a password).
worksheet.ProtectContents = true;

// Allow formatting on rows will enable grouped rows to expand / collapse.
worksheet.Protection.AllowFormattingRows = true;

// Same for AllowFormattingColumns and grouped columns.
worksheet.Protection.AllowFormattingColumns = false;

// Alternatively, if you need to set a password with worksheet protection,
// use the IWorksheet.Protect(...) method to specify a password and also
// enclude the relevant other parameters (take note of the many other
// parameters and their default values that will be used if not specified).
worksheet.Protect("MyPassword", allowFormattingRows: true, allowFormattingColumns: false);
```

Please see the [SpreadsheetGear API Samples > Worksheet > Protection sample](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Samples/API/WorksheetProtection) for more examples of using this new API. See also the following documentation links:

- IWorksheet.[Protection](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet%7EProtection.html) property and [IProtection](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection_members.html) interface.
- IProtection.[AllowFormattingRows](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection%7EAllowFormattingRows.html) / [AllowFormattingColumns](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IProtection%7EAllowFormattingColumns.html)
- IWorksheet.[Protect](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/Support/Help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet%7EProtect.html)(...) method

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
Short answer: not today but soon.

As of SpreadsheetGear 2017 / V8, expanding and collapsing of Outlines / Groups while worksheet protection is enabled is not supported.  This restricted behavior is actually the default for Excel as well, although they offer a way around it (Worksheet.[EnableOutlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enableoutlining) / [UserInterfaceOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)).

That said, the next major release of SpreadsheetGear (V9) will add support for this.  I cannot comment on a release date for V9, but I'll make a note to try to update this answer with a solution once V9 is available (note I work for SpreadsheetGear).

Comment: Ok , thank for answer.  Now i will wait for the next release.